# Opengl es 2. Combine scale matrix with rotate matrix

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es

I have a simple OpenGl es cube, running on Android. I've set up a simple rotation, but now I want to scale the object. I thought that adding a scale matrix and multiplying it as I did for other matrices, would have produced expected results. 
Anyway, it doesn't. Here's the class

```
public class Render implements Renderer  {

    //fields

    private Triang tri;
    private Quad qua;
    private Cube cu;

    private float [] mIden = new float[16];
    private float [] mPro = new float [16];
    private float [] mCamera = new float [16];
    private float [] mResult = new float [16];
    private float [] mResult2 = new float [16];
    private float [] mResult3 = new float [16];
    private float [] mRot = new float [16];
    private float [] mScale = new float [16];
    private float an;

    //methods


    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        tri = new Triang();
        qua = new Quad();
        cu = new Cube();

    }

//I think the problem is in this Ondraw frame method

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mCamera, 0, i, 0f, -3f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);

    long tempo = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
        float an = 0.090f * ((int)tempo);

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mIden, 0);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mCamera, 0, i, 0f, -3f, 0f, 0f, 0f, left, up, z);
    long tempo = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
    float an = 0.090f * ((int)tempo);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mResult, 0, mPro, 0, mCamera, 0);
    Matrix.scaleM(mScale, 0, 10.1f, 1f, 1f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mResult2, 0, mScale, 0, mResult, 0);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRot, 0, an, 0f, 1f, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mResult3, 0, mRot, 0, mResult, 0);

    //qua.draw(mResult2);
    //tri.draw(mResult2);
    cu.draw(mResult3);

        //qua.draw(mResult2);
        //tri.draw(mResult2);
        cu.draw(mResult3);


    }


    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width/height;

        Matrix.frustumM(mPro, 0, ratio, -ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);

    }

    public static int loadShader (int tipo, String code) {

        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(tipo);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, code);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;


    }



}
```

I've tried changing the order mScale and mResult2 and in the last edit I've also set a model identity but the cube doesn't change in size.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it did not work"? What happens? One thing that jumps out is that you appear to build the combined matrix that includes the scale matrix in `mResult3`, but then use `mResult2` for drawing.

Comment: Mresult3 now it's fixed in the edit, but the cube remains the same as before.